# Playing video files

Tags: 2013, silverlight, video

My site has a video library which is using default silverlight player to play videos. But videos are not playing and the error I am getting is

> Media failed to load. This file is in format that is not recognized.

The video files are actually .AVI. So I want to know which video formats can Sharepoint's default silverlight player play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of supported media formats for Silverlight player in SharePoint:

- Windows Media Video (WMV)
- Windows Media Audio(WMA)
- MP3
- MP4

For more details see [Supported Media Formats, Protocols, and Log Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Media Web Part is a Silverlight control. So, all the formats supported by Silverlight can be played using MWP. Look at this article for details on that: 

  [Supported Media Formats, Protocols, and Log Fields.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(VS.95).aspx)